# Почему не работает строка с модулем canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

```
example = canvas.create_oval(x1 - x, y1 - x, x1 + x, y1 + x, fill = random.choice(color))
data["id"] = id(example)
circles.append(data)
data = {}
print(circles)
while True:
    pass 
    for circle in circles:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = canvas.coords(circle["id"])
```

Выдает ошибку, хотя "id" проверено и является уникальным числом. Почему `canvas.coords` не принимает id круга? А пишет что объект не итерируемый.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  module moduli_oval.py line 24
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: добавьте код в редактор Ctrl+M

Comment: какой язык и библиотеки используются?

Comment: Pyton, 24 строка это последняя

Comment: а examples добавлен в canvas?

Comment: не понял. Я его объявил, в первой строке. А как его нужно добавлять подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: _Почему canvas.coords не принимает id круга? А пишет что объект не итерируемый._ - почему ты думаешь, что ругается на часть `canvas.coords(circle["id"])`?

Comment: выведи значение `circle["id"]` и `canvas.coords(circle["id"])` и посмотри что получишь

Comment: canvas.coords(circle["id"]) возвращает None, а, как мне сказали, должна возвращать координаты объекта привязанного к id(example). Странно. Не пойму как заменить это.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно убрать вызов функции `id`:

```
example = canvas.create_oval(x1 - x, y1 - x, x1 + x, y1 + x, fill = random.choice(color))
data["id"] = example  # было id(example)
```

Методы объекта `Canvas`, название которых начинается с `create_`, уже возвращают id объекта, который можно использовать в методе `canvas.coords` (и других).

Встроенная функция `id` возвращает "питоновский" id объекта, метод `coords` этот id не распознает как id объекта на `Cavnas`. `id(example)` - это не id круга, это id id круга (по факту - адрес объекта, который уже является id круга).

Comment: Спасибо, отлично и понятно рассказали. Я уже сделал так, как вы говорите, но только по методу "тыка"))) Получилось запустить программу. Теперь понял, почему не работала более ранняя комбинация.

Comment: @Руслан если ответ оказался полезен, вы можете отметить его принятым. Для этого поставьте галку слева от ответа.